# JSON file parsing issue due to javascript variables

Tags: javascript, iphone, objective-c, json, parsing

I've been provided with a json file to show results in a tableview. 
But when I tried json file validation using online json file editor then I am getting "Build tree failed" error.

I posted this message to my client about wrong json file and then he has posted some strange description which I am totally unaware.

**Yes the json is not a pure json. It has javascript variables which have json variable. For now u can use a webview to evaluate the javascript variables and use the json value. For ex : dp_f : corresponds to list of departure train is a javascript array variable. U may have to eval the variable and store each array element is a new json with key as dp_f and value of array of these values**

Please tell me how can I use this json file which is not pure. What is the way to parse such files ?

Comment: we'll need to see the json file to help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way to evaluate JavaScript (which is really what you have, not JSON) is to evaluate JavaScript.

You will have to use some form of `eval()`.  I recommend trying a JavaScript sandbox, if available to you.  Of course the best option would be to get the data fixed.